# Http Client Request with Certificate throws exception when trying to read a .NET Core endpoint

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, client-certificates

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API host which is running on kestrel web host server. I'm trying to add authentication based on client certificate. From .NET Core documentation I understood that by adding the following code, it makes the server side to validate an incoming request, that it should have a certificate.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(defaultOptions =>
    {
        defaultOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
    });
});
```

I ran the host. From Postman, I tried to call the endpoint, but it returned an error, so I attached a certificate in Postman settings and I tried again, it worked, from that I clearly understood that the server side is working fine (with a certificate it is working and without a certificate it is not).

I tried the same end point from a .NET Core console app through `HttpClient`. But it did not work. Instead it throws an exception:

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..

This is the code I used to call the API endpoint:

```
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("C:\\path\\to\\myCert.crt", "mypassword"));

try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(httpHandler))
    {
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7221/weatherforecast"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };

        var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't know what I'm really missing. I tried almost everything.

Comment: You could try to enable debug-level outout from the Kestrel and other low-level parts of ASP.NET Core and investigate in the logs why the connection failed.

Comment: Postman doesn't require a valid certificate, and CORS policy.  but httpclient needs them.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, since the exception clearly says that it cannot read the data from the connection, I was thinking about something I missed to add, which is needed for the ssl connection. So, closely looking into the request params in the postman app, I came to know that I was adding the Cert, Private key and the Pass phrase, but in the .netcore application I was only adding the Cert and the Pass phrase. So I was missing the private key. To confirm this, from the post man app i removed the private key and initiated the request, as expected the request failed.

Now, in the .netcore I need to add the private key. To do that we cannot pass the path of the private key as an argument to X509Certificate2 object, instead we have to first create pfx file by combining the Cert, Private key and Pass phrase. now, add the pfx file path as an argument to the X509Certificate2 object instance.

Thats it, it worked.

FYI, you can generate the pfx file either by using openssl commands in cli or in online generater(note: do this only for dev purpose)

Thank you